# Laravel Eloquent: Filter a model by its own properties and properties of relations and properties of far relations

Tags: search, laravel-4, orm, model, eloquent

I have a simple and I think often occuring situation, but I was not able to find any solution throughout the Internet.

There are four related models: Place, Location, Province and Country. Each of these have several properties (like a name).

**Country:**
In the Country model I want to find all countries which names matches the given search string, which is very easy:

```
class Country extends \Eloquent
{
    public function provinces()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Province');
    }

    [...]

    public function scopeSearch($query, $string)
    {
        if (isset($string) and !is_null($string)) {

            $terms = explode(' ', $string); // Array of searchstrings

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $query = $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

**Province:**
In the Province model I want to find all provinces which names matches the given search string (like in the country model) but also provinces, where the country name matches this search string. This is also not very difficult:

```
class Province extends \Eloquent
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Country');
    }

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Location');
    }

    [...]

    public function scopeSearch($query, $string)
    {
        if (isset($string) and !is_null($string)) {

            $terms = explode(' ', $string); // Array of searchstrings

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $query = $query->orWhereHas('country', function ($query) use ($term) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                });

                $query = $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

**Location:**
Now it gets tricky: In the Location model I want to find all locations which names matches the given search string, but also provinces, where the province name matches this search string and - and this is the tricky part - where the country name matches the given search string. At the moment I have no idea how I can achieve this.

```
class Location extends \Eloquent
{
    public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Province');
    }

    public function places()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Place');
    }

    [...]

    public function scopeSearch($query, $string)
    {
        if (isset($string) and !is_null($string)) {

            $terms = explode(' ', $string); // Array of searchstrings

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $query = $query->orWhereHas('province', function ($query) use ($term) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                });

                $query = $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

**Place:**
The same here: In the Place model I want to find all places which names matches the given search string, but also locations, where the location name matches this search string and where the province name matches the given search string and of course the country name matches the search string. Also here: At the moment I have no idea how I can achieve this.

```
class Place extends \Eloquent
{
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Location');
    }

    [...]

    public function scopeSearch($query, $string)
    {
        if (isset($string) and !is_null($string)) {

            $terms = explode(' ', $string); // Array of searchstrings

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $query = $query->orWhereHas('location', function ($query) use ($term) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                });

                $query = $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

So, does anybody know how I can resolve this? Is there a (simple) way to do it? Does anybody know a Laravel 4 plugin which might help me with this? Or am I completely on the wrong way and have to do all this stuff for example in a controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Are Places and Locations stored in the database in their own respective table?

Comment: Yes, each model has its own table.